# How can I turn on static Contract checking for the whole solution?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I am playing with Code Contracts, and the idea seems really nice. How can I however enable/disable different aspects of checking for the whole solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, you have to do it Project by Project.

Comment: There are over 30 of these in the solution :(